# Change the state of hr.contract state

Tags: odoo-12

I would like to automate the process of changing the state of the contract based on the date, on the standard I found the function that updates the state but it didn't call in the model, but in the data file.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Odoo `hr_contract` module has **scheduled action(cron)** which call method `update_state` and this method is responsible for updating the status of the contract.

The scheduled action defined in `hr_contract_data.xml` as below:

```
 <record id="ir_cron_data_contract_update_state" model="ir.cron">
            <field name="name">HR Contract: update state</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_hr_contract"/>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
            <field name="state">code</field>
            <field name="code">model.update_state()</field>
            <field name="interval_number">1</field>
            <field name="interval_type">days</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
        </record>
```

This action should be active by default and will be called every day and update the status of the contracts.

So you need to check if this scheduled action in your system is not active and activate it, you can do it in Odoo GUI as below:

1. Enable developer mode.
2. Go to Settings.
3. Go to Technical menu -> Scheduled actions.
4. Search for **HR Contract: update state** and open it.
5. In the right side of the form, If the Smart button showing `off` that's mean the action is not active and you can click on the button to switch it on. If the action is active but you found that it's not updating the contracts status so you need to check the Odoo log to see if there is any error related to this action.